# How to get a larger random number from the c function rand()

Tags: c, random

I am in a coding environment where I only have access to some most basic c functions. #include'ing other lib is not feasible.

In this environment, I can call rand() which gives me a random number between 0 to 32767 inclusively(I think) in my environment.  Is the following code the right logic to get a larger random number that is evenly distributed like/as rand()?

`rnum = rand() * (32767 + 1) + rand();`

Comment: As evenly distributed as rand is.. A high accolade indeed. Could you really not include thirty lines of BSD-licensed code and include arc4random or something to do the job properly, or read out of /dev/random?

Comment: You should say what your environment is, but it sounds pretty junky. Please tell us you don't have any strong need for these numbers to be unguessable!

Comment: A lot of embedded environments are limited in what libraries are immediately available.

Comment: My environment is HP LoadRunner. The code is only compiled when LoadRunner runs a load test with my code(LR script). The script can run on any machine, and I cannot rely on any machine already having some lib files to link with. All the code is used for load testing test systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rnum = (rand() << 15) | rand()` might be faster, but if you need good quality random numbers you should look for an external library. Built-in random functions are generally adequate only for the simplest applications.

Comment: I'd go with `^` over `|`, myself, to avoid problems if you ever port to platforms where `RAND_MAX` is a saner value.

Comment: I'll second the recommendation for [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html). My own [OneJoker](http://github.com/lcrocker/onejoker) library has a good generator too.

Comment: There's no reason to think this would be any faster than OP's solution, and in fact your solution is wrong because <<16 is defined as multiplication by 65536, not 32768.

Comment: You're right, I'm off by a bit. I was assuming the existing rand() was 16 bits, not 15. I'll edit. You're also right that most compilers will optimize the multiplication by a constant into the shift anyway, but there are still a few stupid compilers out there that won't.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, and the stupidest compilers are the embedded ones.

Answer (score 2):

```
static unsigned long next = 1;
int my_rand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return((unsigned)(next/65536) % (RAND_MAX+1));
}

void my_srand(unsigned int seed) {
    next = seed;
}
```

on linux

```
#define RAND_MAX    2147483647
```

your environment RAND_MAX is probably 32767

reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

if you are not memory constrained you can look also at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister the code is embeddable as like as the example above

Answer (score 0):

Before using ANY random number generator for a non-trivial use, it should be tested extensively. [Here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/12/06/how-to-test-a-random-number-generator-2/) is a link to one article on this subject.

A fun background on the weaknesses of even true random numbers is available in the various histories on the code-breakers at Bletchley Park in WWII. The Germans and Hitler for most of the war assumed their codes were unbreakable because of being encrypted with random numbers, whereas the British were breaking all of these codes completely within months because of various weaknesses in the German implementation of "randomness". Many codes were sufficiently "twisted", if not outright broken, within a few days or months, sufficiently to be of use even though not completely broken.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other excellent solutions proposed here, you can also do a power expansion in RAND_MAX, truncate at a user defined MY_RAND_MAX, and discard solutions which would cause uniformity to be destroyed.

```
int myrand(int MY_RAND_MAX)
{
    int j = 0, num = 0;

    // Generate digits for expansion in powers of RAND_MAX, up to acceptable range.
    while (pow(RAND_MAX + 1, j) <= MY_RAND_MAX){
        num = num + rand() * (int)pow(RAND_MAX + 1, j);
        j++; 
    } 

    //compute remainder to determine truncation 
    int remainder = ((int)pow(RAND_MAX + 1, j)) % (MY_RAND_MAX + 1); 

    // If number is within accepted bounds, mod and return
    if (num <= (  (int)pow(RAND_MAX + 1, j) - remainder ) ){
        return (num % (MY_RAND_MAX + 1)); 

    // Else, if number generated exceeds allowed bounds, rerun method.
    }else if (num > (  (int)pow(RAND_MAX + 1, j) - remainder ) ){
        return myrand(MY_RAND_MAX);

    }else{
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

You can check empirically that this method gives you a statistically uniform output in the given range.

I've done so for several trials with different ranges, each with a sample size of 100000, and got an agreement between the variance of the sample and the expected variance to at least 3 sig. fig.s each time.

p.s. I am  not a coder, but a mathematician/physicist who has recently learnt to code, so any and all feedback on the quality of my code would be appreciated.